# Find the value of a if A divisable by 3

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, least-common-multiple

$A=0.\overline{a}+0.\overline{aa}+0.\overline{aaa}\:  \\
\text{If A is divisable by 3, }\: \text{find the value of} \: a\: $

Comment: Please explain what you mean by $0.\overline{a}$? Decimal representation? And what have you tried?

Comment: @EclipseSun yes i meant decimal representation

Comment: $0.\overline{a}=0.\overline{aa}=0.\overline{aaa}$

Comment: Then what do you mean by '$A$ is divisable by $3$' if $A$ is not an integer?

Comment: @lhf can you answer this question with defenitions please

Comment: The only way for A to be an integer and divisible by 3 is if $a=9$, making $A=1+1+1= 3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that$$A=a(0.1+0.11+0.111)$$notice that since $3|0.1+0.11+0.111$ we have $3|A$ therefore $a$ can be anything

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $a$ is single digit natural number (including zero).

$$
A=0.\overline{a}+0.\overline{aa}+0.\overline{aaa}\:
$$

Multiplying both sides by 10:
$$
10A=a.\overline{a}+a.\overline{aa}+a.\overline{aaa}\:
$$

Subtracting both equations we get:
$$
9A=a+a+a =3a
$$
$$
3A=a
$$
Thus either $(A=0)\wedge(a=0)$ or $(A=3)\wedge(a=9)$.

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming you mean decimal representation, and assuming $a\in\lbrace0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\rbrace$.*

We have : $$0.\overline{a}=a/10$$ $$0.\overline{aa}=a/10+a/100=11a/100$$ $$0.\overline{aaa}=a/10+a/100+a/1000=111a/1000$$

Hence : $$A=(111+110+100)a/1000=321a/1000$$

The thing is : $A$ has to be an integer to be able to say that "$3$ divides $A$", which is clearly not the case...

Hope that helps.

Comment: ok thanks you a lot Anthony

Comment: Serif, beware, @Mefitico made a mistake, because $10\times0.\overline{a}=a=a.\overline{0}\neq a.\overline{a}$.

Comment: @Anthony : Not sure why you wrote $\overline{a}=a/10$, I considered the Vinculum notation for repeating digits. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal

Comment: Oh, that's my fault then, in France (or at least in the courses I went to), we mean $n.\overline{x_1x_2...x_k}=n+\sum_{i=1}^k10^{-i}x_i$. That's why I made this confusion